# Shorten array of DOMRect

Tags: javascript

How can I shorten `rects` (e.g. to 1)?

```
<script>
function rectTest(elID) {
  var rects = document.getElementById(elID).getClientRects();        
  alert(rects.length);  // 7
  rects.length =  1; 
  alert(rects.length);  // 7 ???
} 
</script>

<div id="containter1" contentEditable = true style="...">
  <span id="me">Donec tempus, nisi a pharetra placerat.</span>
</div>

<button onclick="rectTest('me')">rectTest</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Element.getClientRects()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getClientRects) returns a `ClientRectList`. The `length` property of a `ClientRectList` is *not writable*, as opposed to the [`length` property of an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length).

The writability of a property can be found using [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor). For example, try running these commands in your console:

```
var x = document.body.getClientRects();
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(x.constructor.prototype, 'length');
// Yields: "Object {set: undefined, ..."
// Undefined setter
```

And compare that to:

```
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4];
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(x.constructor.prototype, 'length');
// Yields: "Object {value: 0, writable: true, ..."
// Writable: true. It's writable.
```

So, a `ClientRectList` is different from an array. How then can we change it so that we can use it like an array?

[`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) called with no arguments returns a copy of the array. We can use this to our advantage. (`x` holds a `ClientRectList`):

```
x = Array.prototype.slice.call(x);
// Yields an array of ClientRects
```

Now you can treat `x` like a normal array: modify the length, call `splice`, call `slice`, whatever you need to do.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Oh yes. It's working.... Thanx a lot. I thought afterwards, it is not "normal array", so it is something completely different. I will study a little bit, what you do in the code... :-)

Comment: ES6: Instead of `Array.prototype.slice.call(ClientRectList)` it is possible to use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to convert to an Array - `const RectListArray = [...ClientRectList]`

Answer (score 0):

`splice` is the solution you are looking for:

```
rects = rects.splice(0,1);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Splicing takes two parameters: (`start`, `deleteCount`).

`start` is the offset you want to delete from. The first offset in JavaScript arrays is `0` and the last is `(rects.length-1)`.

`deleteCount` is the number of elements in the positive direction to delete. If not included the function will splice all elements before the given offsets.

Comment: No, it does not help at all. I tried to do it as you propose, I looked into documentation over and over, but it never delete members this way... and even worse. When I implement your snippet, the code after never execute... the same as I tried before. Some kind of "internal error" must arise.

Answer (score 0):

by slicing

```
var rects = document.getElementById(elID).getClientRects().slice(0,1);
```