# making the new instance from unknown Object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I am newbie in Javascript. I am facing unpleasant situation, in which "every browser" use different Object class for the same thing - DOMRectList (in Firefox) = TextRectangleList (in IE) =  ClientRectList (in Chrome). 
So I try to write code, where I want to create the new instance based on the appropriate *classCollection*, e.g. nRect, which is the item of the particular ...List object. 
I tried several methods, but nothing worked. Here is the sample:

```
<style>
div.cont {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    border:3px solid #093;
    height:205px;
    width:100px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:12px;
    }
</style>
function MergeClientRects(elID){
    var result = [];
    xRects = document.getElementById(elID).getClientRects(); 
    alert ('ClientRect.constructor is ' + xRects.constructor);
    // Firefox : DOMRectList();
    // IE  :    [object TextRectangleList]
    // Chrome : ClientRectList()
    for (i = 0; i< xRects.length; i++){
        if (xRects[i].top > 5) {
            var nRect = xRects[i].getClass().newInstance(); // wrong, but how should it to be written ???
         // var nRect =new Object.getPrototypeOf(xRects[i]).create(); // wrong too 
            result.push(nRect);
            }
        }
    return result;  
    }


<div id="containter1" class="cont" contentEditable ="true">
<span id="me" style="font-style:italic; font-size:12px;">Donec tempus, nisi a pharetra placerat, diam nisi aliquam elit, a consectetur magna enim sed ligula.  </span>
</div>

<button onclick="MergeClientRects('me')">Process rects</button>
```

Thanx

Comment: Try `var nRect = new xRects[i].constructor()`

Comment: Of curiosity, why do you think it is of value to be able to create new instances of these types? Why do you think it is even possible to create new instances? It is entirely possible that these objects, like most DOM objects, are internal to the browser and not creatable from client code (unless a function is provided to create them, such as in the case of `document.createElement`).

Comment: @Tom> no... : Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor

Comment: @DarkFalcon: I am trying to find simple solution. I am just diving into javascript and this is the attempt. If you find this approach obsolete, then I have to find some workaround. 
But back to your question: I just want to use more general approach based on native objects provided by browser.

Comment: My point is I'm pretty sure you cannot. Creating the browser's version of the object is probably not going to be supported everywhere. That means you're stuck with creating your own type of object and copying out the properties you need.

Comment: @DarkFalcon: maybe you are right I do not know now for sure... For example here is perhaps universal example, where you copy the array of ClientRectList (DOMRectList) in order to work with it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631345/how-to-shorten-array-of-domrect-in-javascript

Comment: But that is copying the array, not the objects in the array.

Comment: @DarkFalcon: But may you access the item in the array, find out it's class, then use it's class constructor to make instance of the object?

Comment: _"where I want to create the new instance"_ What is the purpose of trying to create a new instance of `getClientRects()` ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: No, that is what I am saying is probably impossible. It is not a normal Javascript object. Most likely it is an object implemented in C++ and must be created in native or privileged code. This is an implementation detail of the browser, so it doesn't have to be this way but it probably is. Just like you can't just create a new `DOMElement` by a statement such as `new DOMElemet('div')`

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `for..in` loop for `for` loop; removing space at `t rue` `contentEditable` attribute value within `html`.

Note, the values returned between utilizing [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) and [Element.getClientRects()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getClientRects) differ by about `1px` . It is not possible to create a new instance of either `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` or `Element.getClientRects()` using the `new` operator. See also [CSSOM View Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-cssom-view-20080222/#the-getclientrects) .

```js
function MergeClientRects(elID) {
  var result = [];
  var xRects; 
  var el = document.getElementById(elID);
  var  xRects = el.getClientRects()[0];
  for (var prop in xRects) {
    if (prop === "top" && xRects[prop] > 5) {
      var nRect = xRects[prop];
      result.push(nRect);
    }
  }
  console.log(result)
  return result;
}
```

```html
<div id="containter1" contentEditable="true">
  <span id="me" style="font-style:italic; font-size:12px;">Donec tempus, nisi a pharetra placerat, diam nisi aliquam elit, a consectetur magna enim sed ligula.  </span>
</div>

<button onclick="MergeClientRects('me')">Process rects</button>
```

Comment: thanks, but it should be used getClientRects(). I have made edits in the original answer, so the text is broken in several lines now. Your solution is alternative. :-)

Comment: The different values returned between the two are around 1 pixel. Will update answer to use `ClientRect`

Comment: I think I will simplify it and make new object (MyRect), where I will copy values one by one. I was just curious... thank you and Dark Falcon too...